# React Native: RCT-Folly fatal error - 'fmt/compile.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-hermes

I want to enable Hermes for my iOS react native project but I have next error:

```
In file included from ../ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/Singleton.cpp:35:
../ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/FmtCompile.h:19:10: fatal error: 'fmt/compile.h' file not found
#include <fmt/compile.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My config:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.6.1
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.22.7 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.15 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.5, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 14.5, watchOS 7.4
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: ^0.66.3 => 0.66.3
```

My Podfile:

```sh
platform :ios, '12.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'MyWorkspace'

# Default spec repo
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

...

target 'MyTarget' do
    project 'MyProject'

    config = use_native_modules!

    use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
        :hermes_enabled => true
    )
    
    ...

end
```

After some investigation I found that dynamically linking (`use_frameworks!`) causes this problem and if I link pods statically all work OK. But I must use frameworks for my project so how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set header search paths to `fmt` sources directly for `RCT-Folly` target in `post_install` to resolve this issue:

Podfile:

```sh
...

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'RCT-Folly'
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] = "$(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/fmt/include"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong? Why does this worK? In looking at my Podfile.lock, it seems the RCT-Folly version was a v2, rather than a standard date version and I thought there was some mismatch between React Native and RCT-Folly versions, which I read are required.

Comment: didn't work. same problem.